Access the monthly and daily view with App Script in Google Calendar
My goal is to provide the user with a breakdown of their time blocks by colour for a week or for a day, depending what view they pick. When they change the view - my blocks will be updated automatically.
This is the view change button:

I have read the Google Calendar API reference, but have not found an answer.
Could you please let me know what is the best way to approach this?

AFAIK there is no way to interact with the Google UI except through CardService Addons.
